# Detect if a deep link was opened from android app or outside it

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have a problem to detect (with native way) if a deep link was launched outside from app (for example, from browser), for now I check `getIntent().getPackage() == null` but this not working for android 6 because I configured a deep links like **app links** ([see](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/app-links/index.html)) and these has `getIntent().getPackage()`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `getIntent().getPackage() == null` on version before Android 6, and use the `getReferrer()` ([available since API 22](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getReferrer())) on Android 6 and above.

Comment: I don't think that using referrer will work because getReferrer returns the value that  have a parameter referrer from URI. I used this for intents INSTALL_REFERRER when I need to pass a parameter from google store to the app when installing the app first time.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `activity.getReferrer()` or `activity.getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER)` depending on the version code. These methods return you the referrer URI. Then, you can check the scheme by `referrerUri.getScheme()`.

Here is a great codelab example that shows how to track deep link referrals (The 6th step is what you need).

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/deeplink-referrer/#5

Answer (score 0):

Condition is (check in activity):

```
intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_VIEW && intent?.data != null
```